# How to get bond balance or unbond balance when stake in nominator pool

Tags: polkadot

How to get bond balance or unbond balance of specific account when stake in nominator pool? I use staking.Nominators, I can not get the right info

Answer (score 2):

[Sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar) REST API has a set of endpoints related to `Staking` that might be helpful for you. Does `/accounts/{accountId}/staking-info` endpoint give you the expected result? It makes use of [api.query.staking.ledger](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/kusama/storage#ledgeraccountid32-optionpalletstakingstakingledger). An example output can be shown in one of the available public instances of Sidecar, [here](https://kusama-public-sidecar.parity-chains.parity.io/accounts/F3opxRbN5ZavB4LTn2LYcE98Dh1SgGjhSZhz5pAdRdLRhid/staking-info) the link for Kusama and for a random account.

You can also check the Sidecar [docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-api-sidecar/dist/) for all available endpoints.

Comment: yes, I use api.query.staking.ledger to get unbonding info. but now I want to get the bond balance of nominator pool with specific pool member address which is different from the staking in validator.